# Why does {{ form.form_field }} work in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In Python, if you have a Django form `form` with a field named `foo`, you can't use the attribute access syntax `form.foo` to access the field; instead you must use `form.fields['foo']`.

But in a template you can -- and normally do -- use `{{ form.foo }}` to render the field, using the normal attribute access syntax that works for any object in templates.

Why/how does the template `{{ form.foo }}` work when Python `form.foo` doesn't? Is it a bit of special handing that Django does when rendering templates? Or am I just misunderstanding something simple?

EDIT: I know that Django's template language isn't Python and there are many differences from Python. I am just curious why the `{{ form.foo }}` syntax works and/or how it's implemented in the case of forms. After all, normally the template `{{ object.attribute }}` syntax DOES work analogously to the Python `object.attribute` syntax, but in the case of a form it seems to be handled as a special case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django's templating language, as Kerrek SB mentions, isn't Python, even if it sometimes looks like it. `{{ object.attribute }}` *does* appear to mimic Python's attribute lookup, but it is just a special case of `{{ a.b }}` in the template language.

When you use `{{ a.b }}` in a template, the interpreter will first look up `a` in the current context. Once it has that, it will try the following things to resolve `a.b`:

- `a["b"]`
- `a.b`
- `a.b()` (in the case where `b` is a method of `a`)
- `a[b]` (in the case where `b` is a number)

For forms, specifically, `a["b"]` is what is used. You can refer to a field `"foo"` as `form.fields["foo"]` *or* as `form["foo"]`. That bit of magic comes from the form class, though, and not the template language.

Comment: [Here's the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/base.py#L745) of the relevant bit of the template engine. There's some interesting bits in there, like if it resolves to a callable that has an attribute named `do_not_call_in_templates` it doesn't get called. :)

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks! So there are two bits of magic working together: (1) the template engine's rules for interpreting `a.b` including as `a['b']` and (2) the fact that a form is a dictionary-like object in Python where the values are fields (which I did not know!).

Comment: Which begs another "why is the sky blue?" type of design question: why have model fields be accessed through `model.field` attribute syntax but form fields through dictionary-like `form['field']` syntax, even though both can have fields defined declaratively as class attributes? Is it because you can add fields dynamically to forms but not to models?

Comment: @Dougal -- thanks, I must say I do enjoy reading Django's code now and then. I sometimes can't decide whether I think it's approach to things is brilliant or... something else. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The template you're referring to is not Python -- it's written a separate, dedicated sort of [markup language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/) that is *parsed* by a Python program, but it is not itself written in Python, nor is it *executed* directly. The template language offers a convenient syntax for accessing form fields, but that has nothing to do with how Python itself works.

Comment: Yep, I know that. I just am curious why the `{{ form.foo }}` syntax works and/or how it's implemented. After all, normally the template `{{ object.attribute }}` syntax DOES work analogously to the Python `object.attribute` syntax, but in the case of a form it seems to be handled as a special case.

Comment: Check out the Variables subsection in the link provided.

Comment: @Ghopper21: The template attributes are presumably realised as a dynamic container (a "list") in Python. All template attributes are the same "type" of Python object, so they all go into a container. The Python attributes which you refer to are all distinct objects, so if you will that's a different category of thing.

Comment: @Ghopper21 it's not a special case, any dictionary-like object can be accessed using dot notation in a template.